# Radio button color-picker

Tags: javascript, html

The only thing wrong with the program is that the color is not selected, the color is always black, i changed the radio buttons to a single text input element and it worked, so the error must be related to the radio buttons.

```
function hello() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var para = document.getElementById("para");

    var myColor = "";

    var color = {
        green: document.getElementById("green"),
        blue: document.getElementById("blue"),
        red: document.getElementById("red")
    }

    switch (color) {

        case color.green.checked:
            myColor = "green";
            break;

        case color.blue.checked:
            myColor = "blue";
            break;

        case color.red.checked:
            myColor = "red";

        default:
            myColor = "black"

    }

    para.style.color = myColor;

    if (name == "") {
        para.innerHTML = "Incorrect Input";
    } else {
        para.innerHTML = "Hello " + name + "!";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch to use you compare the key value with the cases. In this code, it does not equal any of the cases, so he chooses the default value.

Try this:

```
myColor = "black"

if(color.green.checked)
    myColor = "green";
else if(color.blue.checked)
    myColor = "blue";
else if(color.red.checked)
    myColor = "red";

para.style.color = myColor;
```